# How to know whether mongodb is running on 64 bit mode or 32 bit mode

Tags: windows-7

My programmer install mongodb. Then somehow it doesn't work. I run

```
C:\mongod\bin>mongod
mongod --help for help and startup options
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 warning: 32-bit servers don't have journaling enabled by def
ault. Please use --journal if you want durability.
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=3800 port=27017 dbpat
h=/data/db 32-bit host=haryantoi5
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten]
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] ** NOTE: when using MongoDB 32 bit, you are
limited to about 2 gigabytes of data
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] **       see http://blog.mongodb.org/post/13
7788967/32-bit-limitations
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] **       with --journal, the limit is lower
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten]
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] db version v2.0.7-rc1, pdfile version 4.5
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] git version: 9efe4cce272373b52b96de1309c1fbf
0c984305f
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(ma
jor=6, minor=0, build=6002, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack 2') BOOST_LIB
_VERSION=1_42
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] options: {}
**************
Unclean shutdown detected.
Please visit http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for recovery instructions.
*************
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 12596 old lock f
ile, terminating
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 dbexit:
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets..
.
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 dbexit: really exiting now
```

It seems that mongod is running on 32 bit. I have a 64 bit computer and I want to run mongodb in 64 bit enviroment. How do I do so?

Comment: Install the 64 bit version instead of the 32 bit version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is not in the difference between 64-bit and 32-bit architectures.  That is a warning, and the server should continue running (though you are limited to 2Gb of data under 32-bit).  What you're really up against is the following line:

```
Unclean shutdown detected.
Please visit http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/repair for recovery instructions.
*************
Sat Aug 11 22:57:50 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 12596 old lock file, terminating
```

This means that the database was forcefully shut down, and it has not cleaned up after itself. You want to run 'mongod --repair' to clean up stale locks and bring the database back to normal.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Durability+and+Repair

Pay attention to the part where it recommends against deleting the lock file.